# Android login can't proceed to another procedure

Tags: php, android, json

I'm trying to build basic android login via JSON parser. Here is my code:

```
package com.muzaffar.spycare.Activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.muzaffar.spycare.App.JSONParser;
import com.muzaffar.spycare.App.SessionManager;
import com.muzaffar.spycare.App.Util;
import com.muzaffar.spycare.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static com.muzaffar.spycare.App.Constant.BASE_URL_LOGIN;
import static com.muzaffar.spycare.App.Constant.LOGIN_SUCCESS_MESSAGE;

/**
 * Created by OligoCoco on 11/2/2016.
 */

public class Login_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //declaration
    private EditText app_email,app_password,app_imei;
    private Button app_login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Session manager
        final SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, Main_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Initialization
        app_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.app_email);
        app_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.app_password);
        app_imei = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.app_imei);
        app_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.app_login);

        app_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AttemptLogin attemptLogin= new AttemptLogin();
                attemptLogin.execute(app_email.getText().toString(),app_password.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    public void clickToRegisterPage(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, Register_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /*Validate Email*/
    private Boolean isEmailCorrect(String email) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
                "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
                        "\\@" +
                        "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
                        "(" +
                        "\\." +
                        "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
                        ")+"
        );
        return pattern.matcher(email).matches();
    }
    /*EOF Validate Email*/

    /*Process Login*/

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_Activity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {

                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", args[0]);
                params.put("password", args[1]);

                Log.d("request", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        BASE_URL_LOGIN, "POST", params);

                if (json != null) {
                    Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                    return json;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

            try {
                if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }

                if (result != null) {
                    String getMessage = result.getString("message");

                    if (getMessage == LOGIN_SUCCESS_MESSAGE) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("user_id"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        final SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
                        final Util setUserId = new Util(getApplicationContext());

                        //Save user_id
                        setUserId.saveToPref("user_id", result.getString("user_id"));

                        //Set Logged status
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        //Go to terms
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Terms_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    /*EOF Process Login*/
}
```

However, I can't identify the problem on this section:

```
if (result != null) {
                    String getMessage = result.getString("message");

                    if (getMessage == LOGIN_SUCCESS_MESSAGE) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("user_id"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        final SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
                        final Util setUserId = new Util(getApplicationContext());

                        //Save user_id
                        setUserId.saveToPref("user_id", result.getString("user_id"));

                        //Set Logged status
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        //Go to terms
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Terms_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

When the login is success, I only managed to invoke:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

While other code as shown below is completely ignored and not running:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("user_id"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

final SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    final Util setUserId = new Util(getApplicationContext());

    //Save user_id
    setUserId.saveToPref("user_id", result.getString("user_id"));

//Set Logged status
session.setLogin(true);

//Go to terms
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Terms_Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

What is the issue as I receive no error etc.,
but I am just stuck at login page and not able to move to terms.class..Only first toast message was shown..Your help is really appreciated...

Comment: try to make this a little more easy to go through for someone trying to help out - focus only on the core issue. Here you are asking someone to go through the 100s of lines of code you've pasted.

Comment: what is the value of getMessage if result isn't null and what is the value of LOGIN_SUCCESS_MESSAGE in your Constant class ?

Comment: I managed to fix the code, thanks for the hint @Rasool Ghana :)

Comment: i think you should use `.equals()` for strings , not `==` ?!

Comment: Another great suggestion, thanks @yazan 